# Return all dimensions if there are 3 channels, else return 0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pytorch

I want to plot some images that are sometimes grayscale, sometimes color.

Since I'm using `pytorch`, the transformed images are either `(50, 100, 1)` or `(50, 100, 3)` depending on if they're color or not. Since `matplotlib` cannot take the *former* for a picture, I need to return these shapes:

```
(100, 100, 3) # if it's a color picture
(100, 100) # if it's a grayscale picture
```

Those are the shapes `matplotlib` can deal with. Here is what my workflow looks like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h, w = 50, 100

grey = np.random.randint(0, 256, (h, w, 1))
color = np.random.randint(0, 256, (h, w, 3)
```

**With the same line**, I need to be able to plot images that can either be color or greyscale.

```
plt.imshow(grey[:, :, 0 if grey.shape[-1] == 1 else :]
plt.imshow(color[:, :, 0 if color.shape[-1] == 1 else :]
```

But that's not correct `python` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just write

```
plt.imshow(grey[:,:,0] if grey.shape[-1] == 1 else grey)
plt.imshow(color[:,:,0] if color.shape[-1] == 1 else color)
```